# Raspberry Camera V2 on Android

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspicam, android

I have flashed android (can flash any version necessary to make this work) onto my Raspberry Pie 3 and would like to be able to use the Pi Camera V2. Ive plugged in the camera to the raspberry pi but the android build does not have a camera app to test. Ive tried downloading a camera app but none will install and open on the pi running android.

Is it even possible to get the camera working on a pi running android?

I have tried Android things and the image file it provides when flashed on my sd card does not run. I'm not sure why but it appears to be corrupt as when the flash is complete the usb becomes unreadable by my mac. Usually in my experience the usb is readable after being flashed. I have resorted to using an older version build I found on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search reveals that you could use Android Things. it's basically a plug and play solution; no kernel modifications or user libraries needed, just java code with the standard Android APIs.

Comment: see updated question, have you experienced different with android things recently?

Comment: I'm not really sure why are you using android. Using Raspbian is way simpler for use of the camera module. Also what do you mean when you said that the image file it provided did not run? DId your raspberry pi boot properly when flased?

Comment: Also if you can change the OS for the pi I would recommend using Raspbian only as it will make things very easy for you